# How to change base url of Swagger in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

By default when you enable swagger in ASP.NET Core project it's available on url:

```
http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/ui
```

I would like to use a different base url instead of `/swagger/ui`. How/where can i configure that?

I found that for older versions you can configure the `RootUrl` but there is no similiar method in ASP.NET Core:

```
.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RootUrl(req => myCustomBasePath);
});
```

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The new swagger version provides you with a property called RoutePrefix.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
});
```

Should work for .net core

Comment: the `RoutePrefix` alone isn't enough if you want to use URL prefix like `/prefix/swagger/...` for both Swagger UI and swagger.json file. You also need to set `RouteTemplate` property.

Comment: @IvanSveshnikov Update: I think it works fine now on 2022 without the `RouteTemplate `. :) Thank you! :)

Comment: @OmarMagdy it doesn't work for me on NET 7 VS2022, I had to add RouteTemplate.

Comment: As of .net core 6 this only works when running where the .net core app is running at the root of the site... if you have a virtual directory in front of it (such as behind a proxy) it is still not working. I had to use the `RouteTemplate` to make it work behind a proxy

Answer (score 101):

For ASP.NET Core 2 (and using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger -Version 4.0.1`), a couple things can be done for a full configuration of changing the default swagger UI base URL.

If you want to add "mycoolapi" to the beginning of your default swagger UI URL, like this: `http://<server>/mycoolapi/swagger`, then do the following:

In your Startup.cs Configure method:

```
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "mycoolapi/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    });


    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mycoolapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "mycoolapi/swagger";
    });
```

Then, if you currently have your launchSettings to launch browser at swagger UI upon startup (for development purposes), update your launchSettings.json file profiles section similarly:

```
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "mycoolapi/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyProject.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "mycoolapi/swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your iisExpress applicationUrl value? .. I tried everything but for some reason I cannot make it to work .. In the end I want to host it in IIS ('http://localhost/appName/')

Comment: This should be accepted anwser. Set RouteTemplate is a must now in .net core. It was different in .net framework.

Comment: SwaggerEndPoint part should be like below for relative usage. 
c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API V1");

Answer (score 8):

Other answers didn't work for me in .NET 5. Here is how I added 'docs' to the route

```
app.UseSwagger(c => c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/docs/{documentName}/swagger.json");
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/docs/v2/swagger.json", "My API"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as well in Config

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY API");
            });
```

Comment: Congrats for posting exactly the same answer as the accepted one, but with the lines switched round ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the **launchSettings.json** file.
2. Under the **"profiles"** node depending on your setup you should have one or more profiles. In may case I had **"IIS Express"** and another with named with my project name (***e.g WebApplication1*** ), now changing the **launchUrl** entry to **"launchUrl": "swagger"** solved my problem.
3. If this does not work and you have other profiles do the same and test.

Answer (score 2):

I had to dig through the original docs because all the above solutions did not work. This code in *Startup.cs* is what is working for me:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"./v1/swagger.json", "SapWeb v1");
});
```

My site is a subsite in IIS. So, at first, I had to set PathBase:

```
app.UsePathBase($"{pathbase}");
```

Comment: What is your "pathbase" variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using Dotnet/Aspnet8

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
  c.RouteTemplate = "/MyCustomStuff/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.{json|yaml}";
});
```

should change the URL properly.

---

I found this by following `UseSwagger..RouteTemplate` to the source:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets a custom route for the Swagger JSON/YAML endpoint(s). Must include the {documentName} parameter
/// </summary>
public string RouteTemplate { get; set; } = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.{json|yaml}";
```

Answer (score -3):

The `UseSwaggerUi()` extension method to enable the middleware in the Configure method of the StartUp class takes two variables. A `baseRoute` which is on `swagger/ui` by default, and `swaggerUrl` which is on `swagger/v1/swagger.json` by default. Simply provide a different baseRoute.

```
//Swagger will be available under '/api' url
app.UseSwaggerUi("api");
```

If people would like to learn more about configuring Swagger for ASP.NET Core, I've written a blogpost to get started: https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-1-0-web-api-automatic-documentation-with-swagger-and-swashbuckle/