# asp.net core swagger RoutePrefix

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

i had a api site use swagger to expose api.
dotnet core version is 2.1 and swagger is Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0.0.
my api site is behind a reverse proxy(nginx),  the nginx url is https://www.aa.com/chat, map to backen server http://127.0.0.1:5003/
and my swagger config is :
ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "aa.IM.CustomerApi", Version = "v1" });
                    var basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
                    var controllerXmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "aa.IM.CustomerApi.xml");
                    var entityXmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "aa.IM.Entity.xml");
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(controllerXmlPath);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(entityXmlPath);
                    //c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
            });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "aa.IM.CustomerApi");
            });
```

then, i can enter into the ui https://www.aa.com/chat/swagger/index.html
and then ui can dispaly all perfect, but, when i execute a api (the uri is cus/settings), i found the request url https://www.aa.com/cus/settings is wrong, the correct url is https://www.aa.com/chat/cus/settings.

how can i fix my swagger config to resole the problem?
i had try many way, like http://eatcodelive.com/2017/05/19/change-default-swagger-route-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api/ and [How to change base url of Swagger in ASP.NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116047/how-to-change-base-url-of-swagger-in-asp-net-core) 
but these all can not resolve my problem.

Comment: in dot net framework version, this can config by  set RootUrl, but in dotnet core version, only RoutePrefix can set, and i try it not work correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks all, i resolved it by below config:

```
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((doc, requset) =>
                {
                    var root = "https://www.aa.com/chat/";
                    doc.Host = root;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try rewriting your urls using app.UseRewriter.

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"/cus/settings", "Chat$1", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

Note that this is untested and just written out of my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenAPI v3 then `doc.Host` will not exist. The replacement is `doc.Servers` and can be initialised like this if your proxy sets all the `X-` headers and they are single-valued (note that the `X-*` headers are multi-valued if there are multiple proxies in your network).

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
  options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((doc, request) =>
  {
    string? host = request.Headers["x-forwarded-host"];
    string? port = request.Headers["x-forwarded-port"];
    string? proto = request.Headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
    string? prefix = request.Headers["x-forwarded-prefix"];

    if (host != null && port != null && proto != null && prefix != null)
    {
      doc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new() { Url = $"{proto}://{host}:{port}{prefix}" } };
    }
  });
});
```

More properties are available on the `OpenApiServer` model class if you want to populate them.