# How to configure Swagger in Dev/Test and Production environment

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I have configured Swagger in my .NET 6 Web API project. In local, I can access Swagger file. Below is my code for that.

```
 public static void ConfigureSwaggerMiddleware(this WebApplication app)
        {
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml", "API V1");
                   
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.yaml", "API V1");
                    c.RoutePrefix = "api/abc";

                });
            }
        }
```

Now, I want to configure its URL in dev, test and higher environment like https://devurl/api/abc/swagger.yaml. I am trying above code but I am getting an error as

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7120/swagger/index.html

Comment: if/else? <--- What's wrong with that

Comment: @ScottishTapWater updated my question now. I am still having an issue.

Comment: Is the issue more that you're wanting to set the whole URL rather than just the swagger endpoint?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater yeah. Want to set whole URL for Swagger.

Comment: So as far as I know, you can't have a totally different URL for Swagger as the rest of your app... You can only change after the first `/`

Comment: @ScottishTapWater right. I don't want to set whole new URL. Just want to append api/abc in existing URL.

Comment: does `c.SwaggerEndpoint("api/abc/swagger/v1/swagger.yaml", "API V1");` work?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater no.

Comment: pls correct me if I made the mistake to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid what you want can't be realized if you only changed the route prefix.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerUI(
            this IApplicationBuilder app,
            Action<SwaggerUIOptions> setupAction = null)
        {
            SwaggerUIOptions options;
            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<SwaggerUIOptions>>().Value;
                setupAction?.Invoke(options);
            }

            // To simplify the common case, use a default that will work with the SwaggerMiddleware defaults
            if (options.ConfigObject.Urls == null)
            {
                var hostingEnv = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
                options.ConfigObject.Urls = new[] { new UrlDescriptor { Name = $"{hostingEnv.ApplicationName} v1", Url = "v1/swagger.json" } };
            }

            return app.UseSwaggerUI(options);
        }
```

When we didn't set any config option for use swagger UI, it will set the default URL as `v1/swagger.json` with the default route prefix `public string RoutePrefix { get; set; } = "swagger";` That makes us get the `swagger.json` file to load the index page. While you changed the route prefix value, it will make your API application failed to find the swagger configuration file, which will make it 404 error.

So we need to change both `launchsetting.json` and add `app.UseSwagger` options. I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732702).

Here's my configuration in `Program.cs` and in `launchsetting.json`, I changed `"launchUrl": "api/abc/swagger"`.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "api/abc/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    });
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/abc/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = "api/abc/swagger";
    });
}
```

Then whenever the api application is running, it will direct to `https://localhost:7212/api/abc/swagger/index.html` and show the APIs. Here's my test result.

[image]