# How to add Base Url in swagger(C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

How can I add a base url on swagger ui like this in C#.
[image]

Please refer the below screenshot what I actually needed in which manner.
[image]

Comment: What code do you have now to add Swagger to your app? Is it .NET Framework? .NET 6?

Comment: [how-to-change-base-url-of-swagger-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116047/how-to-change-base-url-of-swagger-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @DavidG It's .net 6

Comment: @RyanWilson It's not that what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this?

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
});
```

Comment: Tried this but not getting the exact result.
I want something like this "Base Url : example.com"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add "mycoolapi" to the beginning of your default swagger UI URL, like this: http:///mycoolapi/swagger, then do the following:

In your Startup.cs Configure method:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "mycoolapi/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
});


app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mycoolapi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Cool API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "mycoolapi/swagger";
});
```

Then, if you currently have your launchSettings to launch browser at swagger UI upon startup (for development purposes), update your launchSettings.json file profiles section similarly:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "mycoolapi/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyProject.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "mycoolapi/swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please see the image above I just added, this is what I need exactly